# Can I cast sanctuary as a bonus action as part of the same turn I hit someone

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance

With *sanctuary* as a bonus action, can a character whack someone then cast *sanctuary* to try and prevent retaliation? Can they then repeat the same combination of attack and casting *sanctuary* as a bonus action for as long as they have spell slots available?

Is that balanced and what was intended?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. With caveats.

There is nothing wrong with this particular spell/attack selection. The only place you'll run into trouble is that you can *only* cast cantrips if you've cast a bonus action spell on your turn.

This is working *as intended* since it balances by consuming a whole spell slot basically every round (if you're going to attack every turn), and by limiting you to only bonus action spells for the rest of your turn.

To be honest, this is a pretty low impact use of a L1 spell. If you want to use this well, use it the turn before you're going to put out some healing spells to keep you protected for a turn or so. Or use it on the tank to make people move around him and eat opportunity attacks, or something. Using it to provide a single round of protection for yourself is probably among the less useful uses of this spell.

Comment: The "limiting you to bonus action spells" and "only cantrips" parts don't really matter when *sanctuary* itself is the bonus action, and the regular action has already been determined to be Attack.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out when you are talking about the impact of the spell, that it is not a consistently dependable combo. If the target makes a saving throw, you can still be attacked.